# Can Reflection be used in CompileTimeInitialize in PostSharp 3.1?

Tags: c#, postsharp

Is it possible to use reflection in `CompileTimeInitialize` in PostSharp 3.1?

Following code worked in 3.0:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string TestField;

    [TestAspect]
    public void TestMethod() { }
}

public class TestAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    private LocationInfo locationInfo;

    public override void CompileTimeInitialize(MethodBase method, AspectInfo aspectInfo)
    {
        this.locationInfo = new LocationInfo(method.ReflectedType.GetField("TestField"));
    }

    public override void OnSuccess(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.locationInfo);
    }
}
```

With the 3.1 upgrade, `this.locationInfo` becomes `Missing Property` and accessing any of its properties cause `NullReferenceException`.

Was I doing this a wrong way or has this been changed in 3.1 upgrade?
If so, can you suggest me the right way to approach this?

PS: If I set `this.locationInfo` in `RuntimeInitialize` things work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use reflection in `CompileTimeInitialize` method and, actually, `locationInfo` holds correct information during that method's execution.

However, the `locationInfo` field is then serialized, and later deserialized during runtime. This is where the problem happens - apparently, version 3.1 has introduced a bug related to serialization in this particular case. You can check this by saving only locationInfo.Name in the field, for example.

It means you'd need to wait for a bug fix to be implemented in 3.1. You may also want to report the bugs directly on the [PostSharp support forum](http://support.sharpcrafters.com).

**Update:** The issue has been fixed in PostSharp build 3.1.30.

Comment: Thank you. Now I know it is not a problem on my side. I will report this to PostSharp forum.